# My nginx hosts are not workinig. I was trying to map my frontend and backend server running in localhost to a virtual host

Tags: nginx

I am setting up a virtual host using Nginx in my localhost(I am using Ubuntu 20.04), but when I enter `https://www.intervue-dev.io` in my browser, output is coming as DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

My frontend server running on localhost:3000 and my backend server is running on localhost:9000.

Here is the configuration of /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   intervue-dev.io
127.0.0.1   www.intervue-dev.io
```

Here is the configuration of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
events {
    worker_connections  4000;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.intervue-dev.io intervue-dev.io;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name intervue-dev.io;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
      listen 443 ssl default_server;
      client_max_body_size 30M;
      ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      server_name intervue-dev.io www.intervue-dev.io;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
      keepalive_timeout 75 75;
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server.key;
      ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
      ssl_session_timeout  5m;
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
      location /test/ {
        return 200 'gangnam style!';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
      }
      location /developer/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3004;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
      location /bff {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
      location /socket {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
      location /whiteboard {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
      location /languageserver {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9100;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
      location /test-cases {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
    }
}
```

Please help me out.